# Using a text file as input for a binary

Tags: c++, linux, bash, redirect, cat

I'm trying to test my homework (knapsack problem) and it's getting repetitive entering all these inputs every time I recompile.

Here's what I've got:

```
will@will-mint ~/code/byun-sp15 $ g++ knapsack.cpp
will@will-mint ~/code/byun-sp15 $ ./a.out
Please enter number of items: 3
Please enter Knapsack Capacity: 10
Enter weights and values of 3 items: 
    Item 1: 3 40
    Item 2: 2 10
    Item 3: 5 50
0 * 0 * 0 * 0 * 0 * 0 * 0 * 0 * 0 * 0 * 
0 * 10 * 10 * 10 * 10 * 10 * 10 * 10 * 10 * 10 * 
0 * 50 * 50 * 99 * 50 * 50 * 60 * 60 * 60 * 60 *
```

Clearly my table is not correct, please do not help me there. NO SPOILERS! 
 I put `3 10 3 40 2 10 5 50` in test.txt and tried the following:

```
will@will-mint ~/code/byun-sp15 $ vim test.txt
will@will-mint ~/code/byun-sp15 $ test.txt > ./a.out
test.txt: command not found
will@will-mint ~/code/byun-sp15 $ cat test.txt | ./a.out
will@will-mint ~/code/byun-sp15 $ cat test.txt | ./a.out >> output.log
will@will-mint ~/code/byun-sp15 $ vim output.log
will@will-mint ~/code/byun-sp15 $ cat test.txt | ./a.out 2> output.log
will@will-mint ~/code/byun-sp15 $ vim output.log
will@will-mint ~/code/byun-sp15 $ ./a.out < test.txt
will@will-mint ~/code/byun-sp15 $ cat test.txt | ./a.out > output.log
will@will-mint ~/code/byun-sp15 $ vim output.log 
will@will-mint ~/code/byun-sp15 $ ./a.out << test.txt
```

None of which worked.  I  need help with my bash-fu, how can I use a string of space-separated numbers in a text file as input for my a.out?

Comment: `./a.out < test.txt` or the unoptimized version: `cat test.txt | ./a.out` should work, if test.txt contents are proper.

Comment: Take a look at [expect](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/expect/info).

Comment: @anishane: I tried both, does this mean there a problem in my c++?

Comment: @Cyrus: I was hoping not to to have to write a script, after searching SO trying to get one command to work

Comment: When you did `test.txt > ./a.out`, you destroyed your `a.out`. Please compile again.

Comment: Awesome thanks @tivn that worked!  './a.out < test.txt' was solution I found here, seemed strange it wasn't working...